# SWF file as screensaver

Tags: flash, screensaver

I'd like to use an SWF file as screensaver.

From [xscreensaver FAQ](http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/faq.html#mpeg):

> To play SWF Flash animations:
>
> Macromedia's stand-alone Flash player has xscreensaver support, as of version 6.0.79 and later. To use it, put a line like this in the `programs' preference in your .xscreensaver file:
>
> ```
> "My Flash"   gflashplayer -root $HOME/movies/my_flash.swf  \n\
> ```

Every version of the standalone flashplayer I found has no `-root` option and I can't find **gflashplayer**.

Also `gnash -x $XSCREENSAVER_WINDOW` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a tree-hugger but using something as CPU intensive as fullscreen Flash when you're not even using your computer seems like using energy for the sake of it.

Be cool and use blank screen (with DPMS settings) instead. It'll cost you less.

Comment: Not every flash file is CPU intensive. I like [this clock](http://www.9031.com/c/viewer.php?img=/downloads/images/cap_scr_fliqlo.jpg) and it's useful for me.